# Bind window handle (HWND) to class name/ component type in unmanaged code

Tags: c++-cli, unmanaged, hwnd

I would like to find out the top level component name of a window from knowing its window handle.
This is done like so in managed C++ code:

```
//handle is the window handle as int
System::Windows::Forms::Control^ c = Control::FromHandle((System::IntPtr)System::Convert::ToInt32(handle));
System::Type^ t= c->GetType();
Console::WriteLine(t->FullName);//This is the top level name of the component.
```

However, I cannot use managed code for the solution that I have to develop.
I have tried to use `GetClassName()` as an equivalent, but this just gives me `WindowsForms10.STATIC. [...]` mumbo jumbo :)
Does anyone have any idea how this can be done in unmanaged code?
I know that C++ does not natively offer any support for WinForms, but I am hoping to get a pointer in the right way. I've seen it done in some solutions, but have been unable to get my code working :(
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does unmanaged component really has a name?

Comment: `Type` and `FullName` only exist in the managed world. There is no way to get around this, unless you write some piece of managed code that exposes it to the unmanaged world.

Comment: The application I am analyzing is written in .NET, using WinForms. I just can't use managed code. When I tried out the code snippet above, I get a real class name ex. System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox. GetClassName only gives me the format mentioned in the question, which is unusable to me, since I need to react to some specific component types.

Comment: Okay. I am aware that I can't use the exact method above, I just provided it for illustration purposes of what I wanted to do. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You cannot make this work, the window class names are auto-generated and their string value doesn't repeat between sessions.  The source code for the Managed Spy++ utility can help you get somewhere but you'll have to drop the 'no managed code' requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what the WinForms code is doing:

1. When a window is created, use `SetWindowLongPtr (handle, GWL_USERDATA, value)` to store a reference to the object owning the window.
2. The Control::FromHandle calls `GetWindowLongPtr (handle, GWL_USERDATA)` to retrieve the managed object reference which you can then do managed stuff with (GetType(), etc)

To do this in native Win32 and C++, create an interface class like:

```
class IControl
{
public:
  virtual const string &GetTypeName () = 0;
};
```

and then derive controls from it:

```
class TextBoxControl : public IControl
{
  virtual const string &GetTypeName () { return "TextBox"; }
}
```

and then in the control constructor:

```
TextBoxControl::TextBoxControl ()
{
   handle = CreateWindowEx (parameters to create a text box);
   SetWindowLongPtr (handle, GWL_USERDATA, this);
}
```

and finally, given a window handle:

```
string GetWindowTypeName (HWND handle)
{
  IControl *control = GetWindowLongPtr (handle, GWL_USERDATA);
  return control->GetTypeName ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer. It is a very good solution. However, I'm not allowed to modify to the code of the application that I am trying to read :( (company policy). I tried calling the GetWindowLongPtr like you suggested and it returns 0, because SetWindowLongPtr wasn't called to start with. I will look into how Control::FromHandle works and try to come up with something.